# Assign value in one column if character in other column is x in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to assign a specific interger/number in a column if the character in another column is x. I have 5 characters which repeat down the column, and in a new column I need to assign a number to each repeating character. Basically each of the 5 characters has a specific number that needs to go in the new column. Please help!

Comment: Please add some more information about what you have tried so far. Add a code snippet with your attempts on solving your issue in order to get help on that by StackOverflow users.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions to what I think is your task (a little difficult to judge as you do not provide any specifica data).
Let's assume this is (like) your data:

```
 df <- data.frame(col1 = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = T))
```

**Solution 1**: `base R`

```
df$new <- ifelse(df$col1 == "A", 1,
                 ifelse(df$col1 == "B", 2,
                        ifelse(df$col1 == "C", 3,
                               ifelse(df$col1 == "D", 4, 5))))
```

**Solution 2**: `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df$new <- df %>% 
  mutate(col1 = case_when(col1 == "A" ~ 1,
                          col1 == "B" ~ 2,
                          col1 == "C" ~ 3,
                          col1 == "D" ~ 4,
                          TRUE        ~ 5))
```

The results are identical:

```
df
   col1 new
1     E   5
2     C   3
3     D   4
4     C   3
5     A   1
6     E   5
7     B   2
8     A   1
9     B   2
10    E   5
```